# CSS: Chrome inspector failing with animation using transform and custom css variables

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, css-animations, css-variables

I was debugging a small dropdown with a CSS arrow.
When I tried to inspect it on Google Chrome (latest version, reproduced both on MacOS and Windows), I couldn't see the properties of the arrow:

[image]

the same on Safari, Firefox, Edge works just fine:

[image]

I have a Codepen where you can see the issue:

https://codepen.io/foyerassurances/pen/9e6fbe8ce9e3c6e767b3b65fb895da79

It is happening because of the `transform` with custom variables in the `keyframes`:

```
    @keyframes dropdown-slidefade-open-effect {
        0% {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: translateY(
            var(--Dropdown-v-padding)
          ); // Works in chrome inspector if removed or changed to 16px
        }

        1% {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: translateY(
            var(--Dropdown-v-padding)
          ); // Works in chrome inspector if removed or changed to 16px
        }

        100% {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
```

Is there an issue with the CSS or should I create a Chrome bug case ?

UPDATE:

I have encapsulated the issue in an even smaller Codepen:
https://codepen.io/foyerassurances/pen/f5a0e23f5c3bbfe69bf092e1f3150a44

(`transform` isn't the issue)

Comment: I would personally open an issue on Chrome (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).
Chrome is implementing a lot of features all the time, publish it and kind of move on to the next ones. They miss a lot of bugs here and there.

Comment: Looks like a chrome bug. On my side, the debugger hangs with a spinner, and switching tabs (e.g. computed) and back keeps the previous tab content with a spinner on top.

Comment: W3C validator also doesn't like the use of CSS variables in the transform. It throws this error: CSS: transform: too few values for the property transform. AFAIK it's OK to use a CSS variable in a transform like this - but hopefully someone can enlighten us.

Comment: I did a codepen without transform and had the same issue

Comment: @A Haworth: The official validator tends to struggle with var() because of the way it works. That error can be ignored. For that matter the official validator is really, really bad for validating CSS these days, and I regularly recommend a more modern third-party linter such as stylelint.